# ajax jquery jqXHR в случае ошибки

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({                   
    complete : function(jqXHR) {                
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

что будет содержаться в jqXHR.responseText в случае ошибки ?

Comment: Очевидно ответ от сервера, я полагаю, при неверном url или пустоту при несуществующем адресе `if(!jqXHR.responseText.length) { empty }`

Comment: у $.ajax есть методы success и error. Логичнее использовать их.